# How to find most connected nodes after spectral clustering on networkx?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I've done spectral clustering on G and created a partition matrix to form subgraphs for each cluster:

```
clusters = SpectralClustering(affinity = 'precomputed', assign_labels="discretize",random_state=0,n_clusters=n_clusters).fit_predict(adj_matrix)
partMatrix = [[] for x in range(n_clusters)]
for (node, cidx) in zip(nodes_list, clusters):
    partMatrix[cidx].append(node)
H = G.subgraph(partMatrix[0])
I = G.subgraph(partMatrix[1])
J = G.subgraph(partMatrix[2])
K = G.subgraph(partMatrix[3])
L = G.subgraph(partMatrix[4])
```

But now I want to run max flow min cost on these subgraphs but be able to set the source and targets to nodes that have the highest weighted edges to the other subgraphs. I am unsure how to even start to go about finding this.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Looks like a mistake in your tagging.  I think you meant to use graph-theory.  ( At 800+ reputation, you should be able to ask better questions and tag them correctly )

Comment: To find the highest weighted edge, loop over the edges and update whenever you find one with a higher weight.